# How can I find my DFS namespace servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I'm taking over for a prior admin who created several DFS namespaces in our Active Directory infrastructure. The prior admin did not document any of the structure of our DFS, so I don't even know what my DFS namespace servers are. I was able to find one, by logging into file servers one by one until I found a server running the DFS Namespace service - when what to my wondering eyes should appear but 2 namespaces, only one of which is a Domain namespace.

I've been tasked to document our DFS infrastructure, but that task seems impossible if I can't find my namespace servers to begin with.

We are running Windows Server 2008r2 fairly consistently across our entire environment. We have a total of 6 domain namespaces.

:EDIT:
So far I have searched laboriously through the DFS Management MMC Snap-in. I've also tried using DFSUtil. I've also done the obligatory internet searching, with no useful results. I should note that, until I started this job 8 months ago, I had never used DFS before, and until this assignment, I've only done some minor maintenance - adding new folder targets etc. So it's possible I've missed something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried the DFS Management snap-in? That'll tell you...

Comment: I have tried the DFS snap-in, and can't find anything anywhere that tells me what my DFS Namespace servers are. I've also tried DFS Util. I should update my question with this information...

Comment: Um... I'm an idiot. It is in the DFS snap-in - in big bold letters saying "Namespace Servers" when you select a namespace. This is why you should not stay up late with a pretty girl on a Sunday night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the DFS Management Console, expand out Namespaces, and make sure you see the Namespace you are looking for.  If you don't, then right click `Namespaces` and choose `Add Namespaces to Display...`, and select the Namespace you are looking for.

Once you have the Namespace visible, simply click on the namespace.  You should see a tabbed interface show up in the middle pane.  The Second Tab is `Namespace Servers`.  Click the tab to see the servers acting as `Namespace Servers`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Click there to get:

[image]

Simply click "Show Namespaces" assuming the domain is populated, and there's a list!

Comment: This is only going to show the Namespaces, but not the specific Servers hosting those namespaces.

Comment: Yes, but after adding them to the display you can see which servers host what namespaces.